# A dependency problem after upgrading 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: 16.04, updates, dpkg, 16.10

I just finished upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10 and am planning to upgrade to 17.04 later.

During the upgrade there were a couple of errors but the installation managed to finish and the computer is running fine.

Except that when I write `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following output:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
iptables : Depends: libxtables11 (= 1.6.0-2ubuntu3) but 1.6.0-3ubuntu2 is installed
systemd-sysv : Conflicts: systemd-shim but 9-1bzr4ubuntu1 is installed
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f'
```

And it doesn't allow me to continue upgrading.

EDIT: I've run `apt-get -f install` and got this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
iptables
The following packages will be REMOVED:
systemd-shim
The following packages will be upgraded:
iptables
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 no t fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/252 kB of archives.
After this operation, 143 kB disk space will be freed.
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/ap/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
(Reading database ... 946072 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing systemd-shim (9-1bzr4ubuntu1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service to /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd by systemd-shim'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service' with
different file '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
systemd-shim
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT: output for `apt-cache policy iptables libxtables11 systemd-sysv systemd-shim`:

```
iptables:
Installed: 1.6.0-3ubuntu2
Candidate: 1.6.0-3ubuntu2
Version table:
*** 1.6.0-3ubuntu2 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libxtables11:
Installed: 1.6.0-3ubuntu2
Candidate: 1.6.0-3ubuntu2
Version table:
*** 1.6.0-3ubuntu2 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
systemd-sysv:
Installed: 232-21ubuntu3
Candidate: 232-21ubuntu3
Version table:
*** 232-21ubuntu3 500
    500 http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 232-21ubuntu2 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
systemd-shim:
Installed: 9-1bzr4ubuntu1
Candidate: 9-1bzr4ubuntu1
Version table:
*** 9-1bzr4ubuntu1 100
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: @user535733: That's only a warning and doesn't address the package conflicts at all.

Comment: @DavidFoerster indeed, was not attempting a complete answer but merely a comment to easily get rid of one issue.

Comment: David Foerster, I edited the output for the `apt-cache` in.

Comment: Looks like the first of the two conflicts was resolved already. As for the second, you mistyped the name of the last package. Could you please run the right command (you can select, copy and paste the command from the web browser into the terminal emulator) and update your question with its output? Thanks.

Comment: I updated with the correct output